# Optical differences between characters within a string of equal length

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula

I'm having a data set with different length of string and they get concatenated into a separate column to be made equal via `LEN()`, `TRIM()` and `REPT()`.
The formulas I used can be seen in the last row for each column (`B:E`).

Althought the length of the final string is equal, one can see that the strings within the "Name with equal length" column are not optically identical/ of "same" length.

As I want to use this column for making new file names via `VBA`, I wanted to explicitly have file names with "optically smooth names". (I hope you get what I mean.)

How can I achieve this? Do I have to calculate the pixel differences within (case-sensitive) letters? If so, how can I do this?

| Text | Place | Length of String | Needed Spaces | Name with equal length | Length of Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SaMPLE_TEXT | P 1 | 12 | 2 | SaMPLE_TEXT--P 1_.pdf | 22 |
| SaMPLE_TexT | P 2 | 13 | 1 | SaMPLE_TexT-P 2_.pdf | 22 |
| SaMPLE_text | P 3 | 13 | 1 | SaMPLE_text-P 3_.pdf | 22 |
| sample_TEXT | P 4 | 12 | 2 | sample_TEXT--P 4_.pdf | 22 |
| SaMPLE_TEXT | P 5 | 12 | 2 | SaMPLE_TEXT--P 5_.pdf | 22 |
|  |  | `=LEN(TRIM(B1))` | `=MAX($D$1:$D$6)-LEN(TRIM(B2))+1` | `=TRIM(A2)&REPT("-";D2)&TRIM(B2)&"_.pdf"` | `=LEN(E2)` |

Comment: You will need to use a [Monospaced Font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font#:~:text=A%20monospaced%20font%2C%20also%20called,and%20spacings%20have%20different%20widths.)  Most modern fonts have different widths for each letter.  For example `i` is a lot skinnier than `M`

Comment: Also use a font like `Courier` or `Fixedsys` or `OCR-B 10 BT` or `Lucida Console`

Comment: In older versions like Windows 7, the Control Panel included personalization settings to change the system font for many visual elements on the desktop, such as File Explorer, icons, title bars, menus, message boxes, and more. However, for some reason, Windows 10 removed these settings, and you are now stuck with the default system font - [How to change default system font on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-default-system-font-windows-10).